# What is the optimal setting for PHP's memory_limit for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, memory

I am on a VPS box with a total RAM of 3GB. I have dozens of hosts running on it. I am trying to install Magento 2 on the box now.

- Magento 2.0.7 recommends PHP `memory_limit = 1G`
- My server is configured at `memory_limit = 64M`

I want to restrict the memory increase to just the new host on the box and ideally only to the process(es) that need it.

Can you share with me:

1. what would happen to Magento 2.x if I ran it with only 64M memory?
2. what processes specifically require all this memory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need min of 500M to run Magento properly but 1 G would be ideal. With 64M it won't even work.

Comment: Interesting feedback @oCodewire. You may well be the first person to solve all the issues I have had with Magento these past few months (http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/37674/h-ferrence?tab=questions). I am scrapping v2.0.2 because someone mentioned it was riddled with bugs. I am proceeding to install v2.0.7 and following the install instructions to a "t". That is where I happened upon the memory limit.

Comment: [We now recommend](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html#instgde-prereq-timezone) a mimimum of `1G` but if you're running xdebug, probably should double it.

Comment: The .htaccess files (root .htaccess and pub/.htaccess) should probably be updated to increase the memory limits as well to match with the recommendation.